# How do you count multiple items from a single column with different values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table in mysql looking like this.

```
Employee | Result 
----------------------- 
Employee 1 | yes 
Employee 2 | no 
Employee 3 | diveded 
Employee 4 | no answer 
Employee 4 | yes 
Employee 1 | no 
Employee 2 | no answer
```

How can I use a single query to get the following result.

```
Employee | Yes | No | Divided | No answer 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Employee 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 
Employee 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 
Employee 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 
Employee 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
```

I tried distinct with a combination of group by but somehow I can't get it into this shape. I am not even sure if it is possible with a single query.

I tried the following code.

```
select Employee, 
Count(Result= 'Yes') as Yes, 
Count(Result= 'No') as No, 
Count(Result= 'Divided') as Divided, 
Count(Result= 'No answer') As Noanswer
from My.Table
group by Employee
```

[image: Attempt]

Solution:

max is not correct to use, and count is also not working.
Sum seemed to be the option that counts the results correctly.
I am not sure why count is not working and sum does work.

```
select employee,
        sum(Result = 'yes') as 'yes',
        sum(Result = 'no') as 'no',
        sum(Result = 'diveded') as 'divided',
        sum(Result = 'no answer') as 'no answer'
from your_table
group by employee
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee,
       max(result = 'yes') as yes,
       max(result = 'no') as no,
       max(result = 'diveded') as divided,
       max(result = 'no answer') as noanswer
from your_table
group by employee
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e447df/1)

Comment: I tried this solution, adjust it but I get the same result for each employee. It just showed a 1 for each result.

So I switched Max to count and this looked better but still I got the same result for yes/no/dived/no answer.

Comment: Never heard of that before, nice website to fiddle around!

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry , the formatting was kind of bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sum seemed to be the option that counts the results correctly.
I am not sure why count is not working and sum does work.

```
select employee,
        sum(Result = 'yes') as 'yes',
        sum(Result = 'no') as 'no',
        sum(Result = 'diveded') as 'divided',
        sum(Result = 'no answer') as 'no answer'
from your_table
group by employee
```